# Failure to download extra data

Tags: flash

how to stop Failure to download extra data flashplugin - installer information , i have downloaded the data two times but still get the message ?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the warning, as I get the same message even though I do have the latest version of Flash installed- what version - as I'm at work and do not have my computer I do not remember.

Comment: thank for the reply , but is there any way to stop this message from displaying , it is very annoying  , i to have the latest flash and my system is 14.04

Comment: hello , after restarting the system few times the message seems to be disappear , thank you  : )